# toggle if class name does not contain

Tags: jquery

I would like to modify the below script to apply the toggle where the classname does not contain the value for "selected_month"

Right now the script is hiding the td's where the class name does contain the value for selected_month.

The td's that contain the value for "selected_month" should remain in tact. All others should toggle.

```
$('#month').change(function() {
    var selected_month = $("#month").val();
    $("td[class*='" + selected_month +"']").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.filter()` method to negate `td` elements that don't contain that attribute:

```
$('#month').change(function() {
    var selected_month = $("#month").val();
    $("td").show().filter(function () {
      return !$(this).is("[class*='" + selected_month +"']");
    }).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

return !$(this).is('[class*='" + selected_month +"']');

Comment: the value for selected_month comes from a drop down list with a list of months.. your solution works when i choose something from the selectbox the first time but subsequent selection dont work

Comment: @user3436467 You could use the `.show()` or `.hide()` method before filtering the `td` elements. Does that solve the issue where it doesn't work after the first time?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It works perfectly now with your latest change. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use :not css selector like

```
$(':not(.printable)').toggle(this.checked)
```